# If you don't make it to next interview, can you ask what skills should be improved?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

If you apply with a company and after an interview they decided not to go further with you, can you ask for feedback? This is so I know what to work on. I know this is tricky as you don't want to sound like your disputing their decision.

I wrote some code as part of a test, and though the program worked they said other people did better and my application wasn't moving forward. I'm genuinely curious which area I could work on improvement.

It's happened a couple times with non-technical interviews. Once the lady only asked two questions and said "I'll pass your application along to the hiring manager" and next week she sent the email (with names changed)

> Hi Bob:
>
> Thank you very much for taking the time to chat with me.  At this
>   point in time we are going to move forward with other candidates for
>   the role, but thank you for your interest in our company.
>
> Good luck in your future endeavors.
>
> Regards, Sue

I'm not very familiar with "pulse checks" or pre-screening interviews, but could this be what they are? How do they work?

Comment: No do not ask. They have no reason to provide the information and every reason not to.  You need to analyze your own performance.  Generally if they ask two questions and end the interview, then you did not answer the questions as they wanted. As for coding tests, think about what else you could have added like exception procession, unit tests, etc.  Was your code clean and consistent. Were there gaps between what you did and what they gave you as the requirement?Think about what additional questions you might have asked about the requirement.

Comment: From relatively a young age, I usually knew what went wrong with an interview...I find it odd you do not pick up clues. Interviews should be a learning and growing experience. In later interviews I also learned some technical stuff. If you are not learning something, you ought to find out what it could be improved.

Comment: You can always ask, just do so politely, and politely accept a non-answer.  In at least one case doing so actually got someone a job-  by being very interested in the solutions to a series of technical questions he flubbed I raised him from strong no to weak no, which was enough he got the job.  He ended up being a great hire having a bad day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you have higher chances of reply from technical people.

Don't expect to get rejection reason at HR level. Simply because they review 100s of applications, perhaps, they were just looking at a different set of skills. Or they could have picked one common factor, such as a Master's degree, which most people had, but you didn't, and immediately rejected other candidates to reduce their work.

If you didn't pass at further stages, you most likely have spoken to a technical person, they will usually give feedback when asked politely.